# Is it possible to redirect from one angularjs directive to another?

Tags: angularjs-directive

I want to do something like this:

```
mymod.directive('SomeDirective',function(parms) {
   // calculate target directive here, based on parms
   // redirect to the target directive, and return result
   return mymod.directive('SomeOtherDirective')(parms);
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The reason is that the directive factory gets called only once, early in the compilation process.

The returned object is used for each directive instance, so I'll have to work with that.